# How to increase Android project’s minSdk version in EXPO project?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

There is a way of increasing the minSdk version of an Android build in an EXPO managed project?

I am using a custom-dev-client with native code. When I run the command for creating a build in Android I got next error: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 24 declared in library [com.squareup.sdk.in-app-payments:buyer-verification:1.5.4]

Any help will be appreciated a lot.

Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, I couldn´t. I used a workaround that was to disable the checking in the plugin causing the problem.

Comment: @VictorGlez How were you able to find the plugin that caused this error? I can't seem to find a way to do this

Comment: @NewUser134 In my case the plugin was Square payment plugin. Then I modified via Expo plugin the Android manifest to ignore the error, but at the end of the day the error continues there. It is a dirty solution, but so far the app is running without problems.

Comment: @VictorGlez thanks for the response. I later solve mine too. Majority of the issue I had came from my jdk version. I was using the latest version which was 17. I switched to java version 11 and the problem went away. Seems most libraries don't yet have compatibility with the latest version which is somewhat expected since it's new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use expo-build-properties,
docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/

Answer (score 9):

There is an expo plugin to manage your gradle properties.

It's called `expo-build-properties`.

Once installed you will be able to add a minSdkVersion to you expo app config, like this :

```
{
// ...
  plugins: [
    [
      "expo-build-properties",
      {
        android: {
          minSdkVersion: 23
        }
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In the root android/build.gradle there should be a setting:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

You should be able to increase/decrease the version there. When you build it'll take this and update the minSdkVersion for the whole application, including your manifest so no need to change anywhere else explicitly.

Comment: The question is for an Expo managed application, if you make a modification in the Android folder don't you lose the expo start capability?